# Jquery UI Dialog + Jqgrid in the same time

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

Problem description:
I have a listing with [Jqgrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) and a navigation bar

> view:true,
>           edit:true,
>           add:true,
>           search:false,
>           del:true

When i select a row and click edit, a dialog pops up, with the fields editable in it.

For one field i registered an event handler:

```
$("#gps_coords").live("click",function(){
        $("#google_map").dialog("open");
    });
```

When  i click in the gps_coords field in the edit dialog, opens the google_map dialog,

```
 $("#google_map").dialog(
{
    width:800,
    height:500,
    autoOpen: false,
    modal:true, 
    ....
 }
```

But the focus or whatever is on the (now background edit dialog), so the cursor blinks
in that form instead of the newly opened one.

I have tryed (at dialog setup):

```
  open: function(event, ui) {
        $("#google_map").focus(); 
    }
```

Note: I have a text-field on the newly opened dialog but can't click in, or change it's value.

So what can be done, to have the focus on the newly opened dialog?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have corrected the problem, in my case it was the following:

Each dialog was modal, and when it pops out the first, then couldn't do anything, i removed from it the modal option, and now only the second has modal:true.And it's working great.

Dialog 1 :

```
$("#dialog1").dialog(
    {
        width:800,
        height:500,
        autoOpen: false,
        //modal:true
        ...
});
```

Dialog 2 :

```
$("#dialog2").dialog(
        {
            width:800,
            height:500,
            autoOpen: false,
            modal:true,
            ...
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that I understand you correct.

But how I understand it you can replace `$("#gps_coords").live("click",...` binding to the edit control with additional [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#editoptions) option of the `gps_coords` column definition in the `colModel`:

```
editoptions: {
    dataEvents: [ 
        {
            type: 'click',
            fn: function() {
                $("#google_map").dialog("open");
            }
        }
    ] 
}
```

To set focus you should probably use the call like `$("#google_map").focus()`, but you will have to place it in the separate thread:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#google_map").focus();
}, 50);
```

Comment: Replacing the $("#gps_coords").live("click",... , it worked, thanks for that, but the main problem remains: I can't click in the textbox on the dialog ("#google_map"), all the time the cursor blink on the jqgrid dialog at the first text field!

Comment: @Kszili: If you want to place the focus on some specific textfield you should use it as the selector in the `$(selector).focus()`. For example is the field has id="mytextfield" you can use `$('#mytextfield').focus()` instead of `$("#google_map").focus()`. If the field has no id you should identify it in another way, like `$("#google_map input:first").focus()` for example.

Comment: @Oleg: I done that , but i can't click in that textbox, as i mentioned, when i try to do that, the jqgrid dialog first textbox element will have the cursor blinking in it.

Comment: @Kszili: I read this, but I don't understand what you mean. One well-known problem with jqGrid dialogs is the "z-Index". Probably it is your problem? You can increase it in jqGrid using [zIndex](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties) edit option (`zIndex:1010` for example). If you has another problem you should better post the URL or a code which can be used to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Oleg: I will post you a link, about the problem, in the comming day, thanks

Comment: I have figured out the problem, see below

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.widget( "ui.dialog", $.ui.dialog, {
    _allowInteraction: function( event ) {
        return !!$( event.target ).closest( ".ui-jqdialog" ).length || this._super( event );
    }
});
```